# Finding where a variable thats imported is coming from

Tags: java, string

I'm taking a Java class and have the following example to help me make my code this runs fine but I cant get my code to run. I figured out the issue is with the strAlt however I cant tell where strAlt is defined in the following code.  Using the debugger in Net beans i found out that when it is first used in the switch test strAlt is defined as the string "03" which is converted into the integer 3 but i'm not sure where the string 03 is coming from.

```
public class NWSFB
{
   /** A class variable containing the Station Weather */
   private String strWea ;
   /** The Constructor */
   public NWSFB(String strVar)
   {
      // this is the constructor
       strWea = strVar;
   }


public String getWindInfo(String strAlt)
{
   String strRet;
   strRet = "The wind direction for " + strAlt + "000 feet is " + getWindDir(strAlt);
   return strRet;
}
/**
This routine will accept a string containing the altitude
and will return the starting position of the altitude weather
as an integer.
@param strAlt A string containing the altitude
@return An integer showing the position of the altitude weather within the station weather              
*/
private int getPos(String strAlt)
{
   int intAlt;
   int intRet =0;
   intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
   switch (intAlt)
   {
     case 3:
      intRet = 4;
      break;
     case 6:
      intRet = 9;
      break;
     case 9:
      intRet = 14;
     // etc .... you can figure out the the other altitudes
   }
   return intRet;
}
 public String getAltitudeWeather(String strAlt)
 {
   // get the position in the station weather string
   int intPos = getPos(strAlt);

   // strAltitudeWeather contains a seven character string 
   String strRet = strWea.substring(intPos,intPos+7);

   // return the result
   return strRet;
 }
public String getWindDir(String strAlt)
 {
   String strRet = getAltitudeWeather(strAlt);
   return strRet.substring(0,2);
 }
}
```

This class is used in order to run class weather as follows

```
// this code will be saved in a file called Weather.java
public class weather
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      // the next line is very long and ends with 352853
        //This code doesn't really end in 352853 I think when it did it was getting   diffrent weather data
     final String FAA_FD="SAN 3106 2915+23 2714+16 0710+08 1010-07 1916-17 222331 213141 203753";
     System.out.println("Start of Program Weather") ;
     NWSFB windsAloft = new NWSFB(FAA_FD);
     System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("03"));
     System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("06"));
     System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("09"));
     System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("12"));
     // etc. for the other altitudes
     System.out.println("End of Program Weather") ;
  }
}
```

Comment: does getWindInfo() ever get called? And if so where?

Comment: It gets called in a different class this helps set up I didn't think it was important to the problem ill edit it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the strings are coming from.

```
System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("03"));
System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("06"));
System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("09"));
System.out.println(windsAloft.getWindInfo("12"));
```

The string enters your `NWSFB` class via `getWindInfo()`.
From there it gets passed to `getWindDir()`
To `getAltitudeWeather()`
Then finally to `getPos()`

Comment: I understand where these strings are coming from i'm wondering where the string strAlt is being defined is that clearer? or maybe this is it and I don't see how but it seems to me like this code is printing to the console the information when strAlt is 3 6 9 or 12 not defining strAlt  I cant figure out what makes strAlt equal one of these numbers

Comment: strAlt is being passed around your class from method to method starting from getWindInfo()